# Android multi-SDK project debug build

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-injection, koin

How to add a debug-mode specific functionality into an Android app which is broken into several SDKs?

Lets say I need to add an OkHttp interceptor to all OkHttp clients to all SDKs. But it has to be added only into the app's debug build. However, when the app is broken into several SDKs, they are published as release builds even if the main app is built in the debug mode. Thus, the debug-specific interceptors inside the SDKs would not be added to the OkHttp clients.

How to overcome this issue? I was thinking to take advantage of dependency injection (Koin) and pass Build type information from the app where Koin is started, but not sure Koin supports this feature.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Build Variants]

You can select what build variant is active of each of the modules of your application.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Comment: I use `publishToMavenLocal` and it automatically creates a release build and publishes to maven repo. The same would happen with remote repos. Maybe I did not explain well, my main issue is with SDKs, which have their own projects and are added as dependencies.

Comment: If you make a release build, then your library should be the release variant. Your question doesn't seem very clear.

Comment: Ah you mean other peoples libraries? You want to add OkHttp Interceptors to SDK's of libraries that you use? or of SDK's you have the source code to?

Comment: by SDKs I mean my own libraries, which I use to have feature specific code. I have full access to their code, but when they are published they are in release build type. But the main app can be in debug build. Then I cannot just use `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) ` in these libraries because they are always in release :-) sorry for confusing language

Comment: The main app module needs to control the instantiation of the OkHttp Client. For example, the library module could have a builder that the main app module uses to create its OkHttp client (and therefore you can pass control the use of any interceptor you need from the app module).  Perhaps show some code in your question about how you use OkHttp in each module.

Comment: I am experimenting with Koin properties and it seems working. I can define any key/value pair and pass it from the place where I start Koin <3 `startKoin {
            properties(mapOf("BuildConfigDebug" to BuildConfig.DEBUG)) } `  The issue with your approach is that the libraries already handle HTTP requests with their local OkHttp and the main app delegates this work to them. That was the idea to separate features from the main app to the libraries.. Not sure if it was good idea :-)

Comment: The SDK must have some public API to enable it to be used? You could enable overwriting of the OkHttpClient Instance on this public api. That way anyone using your SDK can also override it for their own testing. I've done what you say with Koin myself, I will post another answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getAll()` [in Koin](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/146#issuecomment-580213237) for your purposes.

**moduleb:**

Domain:

```
interface Interceptor
class InterceptorFactory(val interceptors: List<Interceptor>) // Here you have a list of all interceptors from all modules
class HeadersInterceptor : Interceptor
```

Koin:

```
object BKoin {

    val network2: Module
        get() = module {
            single<HeadersInterceptor>() bind Interceptor::class

            single<InterceptorFactory> {
                InterceptorFactory(getAll<Interceptor>())
            }
        }

}
```

**module app:**

define your objects

```
 class OtherInterceptor : Interceptor
```

declare them

```
 object AKoin {

    val network1: Module
        get() = module {
            single<OtherInterceptor>() bind Interceptor::class
        }

 }
```

init Koin

```
 startKoin {
        val app = modules(
            listOf(
                BKoin.network2,
                AKoin.network1
            )
        )
        Log.d("TUT", "${app.koin.get<InterceptorFactory>().interceptors.map { it::class.simpleName }}")
    }
```

Gradle:

```
 dependencies {
    implementation project(':moduleb')
 }
```

Comment: @Angelina If you found this helpful pls remember to upvote or mark it as answered https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers